# Spring Boot Web application with Swing Local GUI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swing

I have developed a Spring Boot Web applications. I have provided REST API's for users to interact with the server.

Now i want to write application for admin to interact with server, in the sense change the data in database. I know i can do REST api with admin role and do a authentication and authorization. But currently i have made front end application with python and this i will like to change later on to angular.

So, as of now i don't want to create extra REST api's and the logic around it. Is it possible to create a Swing GUI with the spring boot web application ? So, admin can directly interact with the database.

I can create a separate GUI application for admin, to interact with database, but i have already defined entity and mongorespository in web application. I would like to use the same and not maintain two copies of same.

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call REST APIs from a Swing application using JAX-RS.

There are some resources here. In particular, note the section on RESTful Java clients

https://mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/